# Should we have an Easter Egg tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [multiple questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=easter%20egg) about [Easter Eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)). I think we should have: [easter-egg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easter-egg). Any objections?

Answer (score 2):

[This is a better search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22easter+egg%22+is%3Aquestion) since it references questions only.

Of the 15 questions found, 14 appear to relate to movie/TV [easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) but only 7 actually indicate the presence of a *known* easter egg. The others simply use 'easter egg' as a throwaway term to mean "deleted scene" or as an example of an alternate source.

On that basis, I would say that the proposed tag would be almost wholly useless. That being said, there's absolutely nothing to stop you adding it, but I doubt it'll prove of any worth.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to add it if it will get deleted though. I will probably only do it if this question is gets more upvotes.